# Dart | Flutter | If condition with or operator

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to perform a check using OR onto an input string but I can't understand why it does not work.

Here's my try:

```
    // checking the syntax of the OR operator
    if ((3<2) ||
        (3<1) ||
        (4<5)) {
      print ('test1 ok');
    }
    else {print ('!!!test1 KO!!!');}


    // checking the actual condition singularly
    if ((!value.text.contains('mickeymouse'))) {
      print (value.text);
      print("!!!string NOT contains mickeymouse!!!");
    }
    else {
      print (value.text);
      print("string contains mickeymouse");
    }


    //actual code
    if ((!value.text.contains('donaldduck')) ||
        (!value.text.contains('mickeymouse')) ||
        (!value.text.contains('goofy')) {
      print (value.text);
      print("!!!string NOT contains any of the conditions!!!");
    }
    else {
      print (value.text);
      print("string contains at least one of the conditions");
    }
```

having `mickeymouse` as actual input, I get in the console:

```
test1 ok
mickeymouse
string contains mickeymouse
mickeymouse
!!!string NOT contains any of the conditions!!!
```

so the two tests returns ok but the actual code goes KO... where's the error?

Comment: In actual code, of course one of the negative conditions is going to be met, the text can't contain all of them. Much easier to test for contains, instead of negating everything. It will work if you replace the '||'s with '&&'s, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(!value.text.contains('donaldduck'))` is true hence execution goes into the block which says it does not contain mickeymouse.

For Or operator, once there is true evaluation, the rest is short-circuited.

Comment: Riiiiiiiight! I have to use && instead of || because the condition is negative! Drown in an inch of water... thanks!